# Run a method in a loop to get Max, Min from an Array List

Tags: java, arraylist

**Background:** The method name is computeStatsMean(). It takes the initial value of 100 and adds a weekly profit to it by randomly sampling the mean weekly profit from a normal distribution. It needs to calculate how much a value of 100 would turn into, in 3582 weeks.  I have to run 1000 trials of that method to see how different values of mean weekly profit values from normal distribution gets us the different values of profit. I have to store the 1000 equity return (profit values or "new values") in an ArrayList and get Maximum, Minimum, Median from it.

**Problem:** I'm able to run method and do sampling and all. But i'm unable to run it for 1000 trials. I tried calling the method in the main 1000 times (1000 for loop) but it replaced the old value with the new one in the ArrayList.

**Code:**

```
class Sample extends SimulateMarket{ 

public ArrayList<Double> data = new ArrayList<Double>();
public ArrayList<Double> myData = new ArrayList<Double>();
private double mean, stdDev; 
private Random random;
private SimulateMarket mySim = new SimulateMarket(); //mySim is an instance of SimulateMarket class used to access variables of Simulate Class

//Constructor 
public Sample(){ //Constructor used for the Distributional Technique
    random = new Random();
    int size = 3582;
    for(int i=0; i<size ; i++) 
        data.add(0.0016+random.nextGaussian()*0.0205);      //Random sampling from Normal Distribution 
    System.out.println(this); //for printing the results
}

//Getters (Mean, Standard Deviation, Median)
public double getMean(){
    double sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<mySim.WEEK; i++)
        sum += data.get(i);
    return sum/data.size();
}

public void computeStatsMean(){
    double equity = 100;
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){ 
        equity = equity*(1+getMean());
    }
    myData.add(equity);
    System.out.println("mean : " + getMean());

    for(Double num: myData){
        System.out.println("with mean:" + num);
    }

}

class SimulateMarket{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){ 
        Sample equity = new Sample();
        equity.computeStatsMean(); 

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Why do you need mySim when your class extends SimulateMarket? Besides, your class does the random stuff in the constructor so you should create a new instance when you want to get new results (or rework your code). At any rate in the future you should also post your main.

Comment: How you are invoking computeStatsMean() from main()?

Comment: You are extending ‘SimulaeMarket’ you don’t need to create its instance (think inheritance). Use e.g. this.WEEK to access members of SimulateMarket. You can delete this ‘private SimulateMarket mySim = ....’ line

Comment: Also, can you show your main() here? You might be resetting data or myData on every instantiation on this class in main()

Comment: i have edited the code and added the main method. @nabsATX sure i'll do that!

Comment: @GokulNathKP i have edited the code and added main method above.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new instance of `Sample` every time inside `for-loop` in `main()`.

```
Sample equity = new Sample();
```

Hence when invoking `equity.computeStatsMean();` old values are lost.

Try like below:

```
Sample equity;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    equity = new Sample();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { 
        equity.computeStatsMean(); 
    }
}
```

In `computeStatsMean()` change:

```
equity = equity*(1+getMean());
```

to

```
equity = equity*(i+getMean());  // use i instead of 1
```

In `computeStatsMean()`, start the counter value from 1 instead of 0. (Hope you can figure out why!)

Comment: Yes. Instead of adding to ArrayList in Sample class, make computeStatsMean() to return the values and create an ArrayList in your main() and add the values.

Comment: i've posted the code above. It's giving me the same "1000 values."

Comment: Change equity = equity*(1+getMean()); to equity = equity*(i+getMean());

Comment: Sir it's giving me "Infinity" as output.

Answer (score 0):

I placed the computeStatsMean() *renamed it to Distributional* method in the SimulateMarket class and used the Sample class to hold the values. It's working now.

```
class SimulateMarket{ //Application Class (it contains the Main Method)

//public instance variables
public double meanWeekly = 0.0016;  //Average weekly return
public double median = 0.0029; //the middle value is known as Median 
public final int WEEK = 3582;  //Data calculate over the course of 3582 weeks 
public final int WEEK_YEAR = 52; //The number can never changes; hence, "final." 
//private instance variables
private double meanYearly = meanWeekly * WEEK_YEAR; //Formula for average yearly return
private double stdDev = 0.0205;

public double Distributional(){
    Sample mySampleA = new Sample();
    double equity = 100;
    for(int i=0; i<3582; i++){ 
        equity = equity*(1+mySampleA.getMean());
    }
    return equity;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Sample b = new Sample();
    b.computeStats();
}
}

class Sample{
public void computeStats(){
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        myDataA.add(super.Distributional());
    }
    for(Double num: myDataA){
        System.out.println(num);
    }
    System.out.println(toStringA());
}

public String toStringA(){
    return String.format("\nDistrubution: size = %d, mean = %.2f, stdDev = %.2f, min = %.2f, max = %.2f, median = %.2f", myDataA.size(), getMeanA(), getStdDevA(mean), Collections.min(myDataA), Collections.max(myDataA), getMedianA()); 
}
}
```